# Rotation of an exponential operator acting in Hilbert space? Interpretation in a certain subspace.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, differential-operators

I have a self-adjoint operator $h$ acting in the Hilbert space $L^2(R^3)$ that has the following eigenvalues
$$
h \varphi_s= \varepsilon_s \varphi_s\;,\quad s=1,2,... ,
$$ 
where $\varphi_s$ are orthonormal square integrable eigenfunctions:
$$
\langle \varphi_s,\varphi_{s'}\rangle = \int_{R^3} \varphi_s^*(\vec r) \varphi_{s'}(\vec r) \; \text d^3 r = \delta_{ss'} \;.
$$
The first $N$ eigenvalues are negative, $\varepsilon_i<0, 1\leq i\leq N$, whereas all other eigenvalues are positive, $\varepsilon_a>0$ for $a>N$.

I will also make use of the position operator (multiplication operator) $X$ acting like,
$$
(X f)(\vec r) = \vec r f(\vec r)\;,\quad \forall f\in L^2(R^3)\;.
$$

My question is, how can I interpret the operators

$$
A(\vec G , \vec G', \tau) = \text e^{-\text i \vec G X} \, \text e^{-h\tau} \,\text e^{-\text i \vec G' X}
$$
or
$$
B(\vec G , \vec G', t) = \text e^{-\text i \vec G X} \,\text e^{\text i h t} \,\text e^{-\text i \vec G' X}\,.
$$
where $\vec G,\vec G'\in R^3$ and $\tau,t \in R^+$?

In particular I am interested in the matrix elements 
$$\langle \varphi_i | A(\vec G , \vec G', \tau)|\varphi_j\rangle$$
or
$$\langle \varphi_i | B(\vec G , \vec G', t)|\varphi_j\rangle$$ with $1<i,j<N$. So I am only interested in how they act in the subspace where $h$ has negative eigentvalues.

Can I think of $A$ and $B$ as rotations of $\text e^{-h \tau}$ and $\text e^{\text i h t}$ ? And is there any strategy to simplify/decompose/approximate $A$ or $B$ since I am only interested in their action in the described subspace? Or can you recommend any literature?

Actually I am only interested in this operator which will turn out to be more convenient regarding to the question.

PS: I am a physicist, so please don't overestimeate my mathematical vocabulary.

PPS: The operator $h$ is the Hartree-Fock operator, acting like
$$
(hf)(\vec r) = -\frac{1}{2}(\vec \nabla^2f)(\vec r) + \int_{R^3} \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{|\varphi_i(\vec r')|^2}{|\vec r - \vec r'|} f(\vec r) \,\text d^3 r'  - \int_{R^3} \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\varphi_i^*(\vec r')f(\vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}\varphi_i(\vec r) \,\text d^3 r' 
$$
where $\varphi_i$ are its eigenvectors as defined above.

Comment: Just a some quick guesses: $\exp(iGX)$ should be a momentum shift by $G$ (take the Fourier transform), in general these should not leave your subspace invariant for generic $G$. $\exp(iht)$ should be just a time propagation (this leaves all combination of eigenspaces invariant), but $\exp(-ht)$ seems weird, looks like some decay at rate $ih$. You can probably approximate your operators using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff-formula. In particular, this involves looking at how your generators $X$ and $h$ interact.